GLB2GLTF for windows command line
What is the best solution to batch convert GLB into GLTF, by Windows command line ?
if this is not possible, maybe GLB to FBX-ascii format?
I want to edit the content of GLTF models, so i need to read model's data in plain text.

One option is to install NodeJS for Windows and use gltf-transform from the command line: https://gltf-transform.dev/cli
